# Expresso Store: Updating stock after order completed

Tags: expresso-store, plugin, extension

Is there a way in Expresso Store when refunding or deleting an order record (eg with Extension Hooks) to modify the Stock levels.

For example if an order is placed for 10 items and is subsequently cancelled or refunded can the inventory for that item/these items be modified accordingly?